# Bash: scp all files in a directory, but not the subdirectory

Tags: bash, scp

I would like to copy all files from a remote destination in a particular directory `writegrid`, but not the subdirectories, e.g. the files in `writegrid/output_files`.

This

```
scp -r cory@blah.com:~/writegrid/* ./
```

will copy the files in the `writegrid/output_files` over as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Don't use the `-r` flag. It tells `scp` to copy recursively.

Comment: This solution gives a warning "not a regular file": it tries to copy also the subfolder. Is there a way to avoid it completely?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi This answer has details on the error that you are getting: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52634/error-using-scp-not-a-regular-file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52634/error-using-scp-not-a-regular-file)

Comment: I read the link: it made me think about the following (if every file has explicit extension): `scp cory@/path:~/writegrid/*.* ./`

Answer (score 2):

use '' in your path as below

```
scp cory@blah.com:'~/writegrid/*' .
```